# How we can make release if build has maximum life time 30 days in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

I found that we can define build life time from “Retention” and it is maximum 30 days. Consider I have a release named “Release1” and it is associated with build artifact from Build 1.0.2016123.1. Now I want to perform release after 40 days from build creation. In this case will Release1 possible from Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)?
If not possible to Release, then how we can manage this type of scenario?

Waiting for your valuable response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "Retain indefinitely" option you can set for the build as an exception of the retention policy:
[image]

> **Managed completed builds:** After a build has completed, you can rate the quality of the build. You can request a new build for any
>   completed build. You can delete completed builds that are no longer
>   required.
>
> You can specify that a build should be retained indefinitely, as an
>   exception of the defined retention policy. For example, you might do
>   this for released builds.

From Release:

[image]

Comment: Hi Eddie. Thank you very much for your solution and quick response.
I just have another issue. 
I think i can do same for the release like following way
http://hasibulhaque.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Retain-indefinitely_In_Release.jpg

If i make release "Retain indefinitely" it is not showing the "Retain indefinitely" status.

Comment: @Hasibul I cannot reproduce it. The status shows correctly. I added a screenshot in my answer for your reference.

Comment: Thank you again for updating the response. Yes now it is working as I clear the browser cache and reload it.